# collapsible column

Tags: css, jsp

i have a requirement. could anyone please help me out in solving this.

i have a column(td) of width 350px. if the content of that column exceeds, then the value of the adjacent column is being pushed to the right. so i am trying to implement a collapsible column (show/hide). the column should display only the content that would fit within the 350px width and the rest of the content should be displayed when "show" link is clicked in that column. how can i do that?

i didnt come across any example which meets my requirement. Please help..

Comment: i tried using JSP Wiki Styles but wasn't successful..

Answer (score 0):

Following is a part of my code. I am trying to implement for the collapsible column for the second td.

```
<table style="width:760px; line-height: 25px; font-weight:bold; padding:8px; margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 3px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-top: 1px dotted #0A7A48; border-bottom: 1px dotted #0A7A48; ">
                                <table style="width:760px; line-height: 25px; font-weight:bold;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width:60px; text-align:left; color:#000; padding-left: 3px;"> Qty </td>
                                        <td style="width:390px; text-align:left; color:#000;"> Part# / Description </td>
                                        <td style="width:210px; text-align:left; padding-left: 3px; color:#000;"> Manufacturer </td>
                                        <td style="width:50px; color:#000;"><span style="width:48px;"> &nbsp; </span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <tr><td>

                        <s:iterator value="readQuoteList" var="entry">
                            <s:iterator value="#entry.value" var="arrayList">
                                <table style="width:760px; line-height: 25px; font-weight:bold;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width:60px; text-align:left; padding-left: 3px;"><s:property value="qtyordered"/></td>
                                        <td style="width:390px; text-align:left; padding-left: 3px;"><s:property value="shortDesc"/></td>
                                        <td style="width:210px; text-align:left; padding-left: 30px;"><s:property value="manufacturerName"/></td>
                                        <td style="width:50px; color:#0A7A48; float: right;"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="removeItem('<s:property value="#entry.key"/>')">Remove</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </s:iterator>
                        </s:iterator>

                    </td></tr>
                    <tr><td align="center">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>
                            <td style="padding-right:5px;"><a class="productDetailbutton" style="text-decoration:none; float: right; cursor:pointer;" onclick="saveHashListItm();">
        <span id="saveHashListItm">Save List</span></a></td>
                            <td><a class="productDetailbutton" style="text-decoration:none; float: right; cursor:pointer;" onclick="removeAllItem()">
        <span>Remove</span></a></td>
                        </tr></table>
                    </td></tr>
                </table>
```